# MediaStreamAudioSourceNode を複製する理由

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html5

Railsでマイク入力を録音したいのでまず[`recorderjs`](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)を使ったサンプル[`AudioRecorder`](https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder/)のサンプルを確認して、次に`AudioRecorder`の`main.js`ののソースを読もうとしてるのですが、HTML5のAudioContextを全く知らないため読み進めても行けない状態です。

最低限`recorderjs`にマイクから録音したデータを流すだけの理解が欲しい状態です。

https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder/blob/master/js/main.js#L138-L152

```
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
function gotStream(stream) {
    inputPoint = audioContext.createGain();

    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    realAudioInput = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    audioInput = realAudioInput;
    audioInput.connect(inputPoint);

//    audioInput = convertToMono( input );

    analyserNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyserNode.fftSize = 2048;
    inputPoint.connect( analyserNode );

    audioRecorder = new Recorder( inputPoint );
```

`createGain`がボリュームを司る`GainNode`を作り、`createMediaStreamSource`が`MediaStreamAudioSourceNode`を作るなど、ぼんやりとわかるんですが

何故ここで取得したNodeの複製を行っているのでしょうか？

```
    audioInput = realAudioInput;
    audioInput.connect(inputPoint);
```

まっと簡単な問題解決の道のりがあるなら、そちらを教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そのサンプルに用意された、モノラル変換機能のためのコードです。

`audioInput` の方は [`toggleMono()`](https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder/blob/master/js/main.js#L125) を呼び出すたびに `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` と、モノラル変換した後の `ChannelMergerNode` が交互に切り替わります。このため、元のNodeを `realAudioInput` に保持しているのです。

```
function toggleMono() {
    if (audioInput != realAudioInput) {
        audioInput.disconnect();
        realAudioInput.disconnect();
        audioInput = realAudioInput;
    } else {
        realAudioInput.disconnect();
        audioInput = convertToMono( realAudioInput );
    }

    audioInput.connect(inputPoint);
}
```

また、`audioInput = realAudioInput` は全く同じNodeを別の変数に代入しているだけで、複製は行っていません。これを行ったかどうかで Web Audio API の挙動が変わることはないはずです。

Recorderjs にもサンプルが用意されているようなので、そちらを確認されてはいかがでしょうか？

https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/example_simple_exportwav.html

Comment: 解説ありがとうございます。 recorderjs 自体のサンプルを確認してみます。